Updating an element in array in AVR Assembly
so i'm trying to update an element in array which get used to print the value inside it but after updating the array, what gets printed is still same, the printer used array buffer and i wanna get the first element on message and put it on the first element of buffer
uno.s
;------------------------
; Assembly Code
;------------------------
#define __SFR_OFFSET 0x00
#include "avr/io.h"
;------------------------
.global init_serial
.global print_msg
.global print_buff
;------------------------
init_serial:

    CLR   R24
    STS   UCSR0A, R24               ;clear UCSR0A register
    STS   UBRR0H, R24               ;clear UBRR0H register
    LDI   R24, 103                  ;& store in UBRR0L 103 value
    STS   UBRR0L, R24               ;to set baud rate 9600
    LDI   R24, 1<<RXEN0 | 1<<TXEN0  ;enable RXB & TXB
    STS   UCSR0B, R24
    LDI   R24, 1<<UCSZ00 | 1<<UCSZ01;asynch, no parity, 1 stop, 8 bits
    STS   UCSR0C, R24
    RET
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

buffer: .ascii "Tetha"
        .byte 10,13,0

loop:
  rjmp loop

light:
   ldi   R24, 0b00000001
   out   0x05, R24
   ;rjmp loop
   ret

print_buff:
    lds r16, message
    sts buffer, r16
    call light
    RET

print_msg:

    LDI   R30, lo8(buffer)
    LDI   R31, hi8(buffer)         ;Z points to string message
agn:LPM   R18, Z+                   ;load char of string onto R18
    CPI   R18, 0                    ;check if R18=0 (end of string)
    BREQ  ext                       ;if yes, exit
    ;--------------------------------------------------------------------
l1: LDS   R17, UCSR0A
    SBRS  R17, UDRE0                ;test data buffer if data can be sent
    RJMP  l1
    STS   UDR0, R18                 ;send char in R18 to serial monitor
    ;--------------------------------------------------------------------
    RJMP  agn                       ;loop back & get next character
    ;--------------------------------------------------------------------
ext:RCALL delay_sec
    RET
;------------------------------------------------------------------------
message:
    .space 32, 0x41
    .ascii "b"
    .byte 10,13,0
;------------------------------------------------------------------------
delay_sec:                          ;3s delay
    LDI   R20, 255
l4: LDI   R21, 255
l5: LDI   R22, 255
l6: DEC   R22
    BRNE  l6
    DEC   R21
    BRNE  l5
    DEC   R20
    BRNE  l4
    RET


uno.ino
//------------------------------------------------
// Programming Serial Port - Printing Text Message
//------------------------------------------------
extern "C"
{
  void init_serial();
  void print_buff();
  void print_msg();
}
//----------------------------------------------------
void setup()
{
  init_serial();
  print_buff();
}
//----------------------------------------------------
void loop()
{
  
  print_msg();
}

i'm using this website's tutorial but still updating the element does not work...

Your assembly functions clobber call-saved registers. See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Call-Saved_Registers

Your buffer is located in flash, in the .text section actually, as you didn't provide a section.  You can read from that location with LPM, but you cannot write to it with STS.  Same applies to message.
For sections, see for example the AVR-LibC manual on sections:

Memory Sections
Assembler Directives

You would put that into the .data section, like with
.data
.type buffer,@object
buffer: .ascii "Tetha"
        .byte 10,13,0
.size buffer, . - buffer

.text ;; following is code

Also notice that

"Theta" will not be 0-terminated, maybe consider .asciz.
buffer may not be initialized at startup.  Make sure that __do_copy_data is referenced when you are using the default startup code.  When you have custom startup code, you will have to initialize buffer by hand.


i'm using this website's tutorial

They are using other assembler syntax, not GNU's avr-as.  When you want to combine C/C++ and assembly, or make use of C library functions, then the GNU assembler is the correct way to go.
The claim that all assembly has to be passed through avr-gcc first is of course not corret, though it's the easiest way to make use of things like C macros and #include <avr/io.h> etc.  AVR-LibC has some (inline) assembly tutorials that are using GNU assembler syntax and semantics.

uno.s

Finally, the s extension means "assembly" source to avr-gcc, so it will call the assemlber with appropriate options, and then pass the result to the linker.  When you are using the C preprocesser, as indicated by the # directives, the file extension would be sx or S, or you could compile with -x assembler-with-cpp file.asm.  Notice however that the driver might overwrite an s file when it Keeps temporary files as with -save-temps.
